# Resetting score to 0 after quiz completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, counter, reset

## Problem

I have a `resetQuiz()` quiz button at the bottom of the page, which is supposed to set the score back to 0, but if the person has gotten 25 correct answers, clicks `.button__reset` and then does the quiz again, it goes to 26 instead of 0.

Live link: https://s3.amazonaws.com/bsunproduction/yearinreview/index.html

### scripts.js

```
/*-------------------------------------
QUIZ
--------------------------------------*/

// Keep track of score
function showScoreBox() {
    var scrollDepth = $(window).scrollTop();
    var divPosition = $(".quiz__header").offset().top - 45;
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    // console.log(windowWidth);

    if (scrollDepth > divPosition && (windowWidth > 768)) {
        $(".quiz__score").show();
        $(".quiz__score--mobile").hide();
    } else {
        $(".quiz__score").hide();
        $(".quiz__score--mobile").show();
    }
} showScoreBox();

$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    showScoreBox();
});

$(window).on("resize", function(){
    showScoreBox();
});

var score = 0;

$(document).on("click", ".quiz__response", function(){
    $(this).siblings().addBack().addClass("is--unclickable");
    $(this).siblings().show("quiz__info");  // Show extra info
    console.log("Clicked");

    if ($(this).hasClass("answer--true")) {
        $(this).addClass("is--true");
        $(this).find("i").show();
        $(this).siblings().find("i").show();

        // Update score
        score++
        console.log(score);
        $(".quiz__correct").html(score);
        $(".quiz__correct--mobile").html(score);
        rainConfetti();
    } else {
        // $(this).addClass("is--true");
        // $(this).siblings().addClass("is--false");
        // $("quiz__info").removeClass("is--false");
        $(this).addClass("is--false");
        $(this).find("i").show();
        $(this).siblings().find("i").show();
    }
});

/*-------------------------------------
RESET
--------------------------------------*/

function resetQuiz() {
    var score = 0;
    $(".quiz__response").removeClass("is--true is--false");
    $(".quiz__response").removeClass("is--unclickable");
    $(".fa-check").hide();
    $(".fa-times").hide();
    $(".quiz__correct").html(score);
    $(".quiz__correct--mobile").html(score);
}

$(".button__reset").on("click", function(){
    var score = 0;
    $("canvas").hide();
    resetQuiz();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new variable & assigning it the value 0 instead of the global one.

Instead of `var score = 0;` use `score = 0;` inside **resetQuiz**

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the score again inside the resetQuiz

```
function resetQuiz() {
    //var score = 0;
    // should be
    score = 0;
    $(".quiz__response").removeClass("is--true is--false");
    $(".quiz__response").removeClass("is--unclickable");
    $(".fa-check").hide();
    $(".fa-times").hide();
    $(".quiz__correct").html(score);
    $(".quiz__correct--mobile").html(score);
}
```

since local variable score was set to zero, it's not reflected in the outside score variable.

Answer (score 1):

Change `var score = 0; to score = 0;`

Do this for all cases except for the initial one. In javascript it is possible to have two variables that has both the same name. So when you are saying:

var score = 0;

You are creating a new variable then setting it to 0. Where as the original still has it's old value.